# Competing Consumers in RabbitMQ via NServicebus

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

Does anyone have a solution to this problem.

I have the following configuration.

2 Servers.

I am using RabbitMQ

I am using NServiceBus to facilitate messaging

There is one NSB instance per server confgiured with 8 threads each.

This config produces the following Consumer List

[image]

The problem I have is that I want to load balance the processing of reports across different servers. What happens is, when I issue 8 long running reports,  they are processed by a single server, in this example NNPCSAPP67. When I issue the 9th, 10th, 16th etc report, they go to NNPCSAPP66, the 17th goes back to NNPCSAPP67. I guess this is expected behaviour by RabbitMQ.

Is there anyway to get rabbit or NSB to process the reports on different servers. So the first report message should go to NNPCSAPP66 then the next to 67 then back to 66 etc.
I know I could set the thread count to 1 but that won't work as I have the capacity to process more than one report at a time.

Comment: What about setting `prefetch-count=1`, so then each consumer will take at most 1 message at a time and will not block others from execution by other consumers on other servers?

Comment: Won't that reduce the processing thread on the reports server to one. So at most I will only have 2 reports processing on both servers at anyone time? The report generation is done in the message handler so the dequeue happens after the report generates.

Comment: no, prefetch count isn't tied to the threads but we default prefetch == num threads if you're on NServiceBus.RabbitMQ 2.1 and above http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/rabbitmq/configuration-api

Comment: So will setting the prefect count to one force the messages onto different consumers for each message processed but still allow me to process n number of reports where n is equal to the thread count. So if I have publish 8 GenerateReport messages then I should expect to consume 4 on one server and 4 on the other?